# How to center the text with background image?

Tags: html, css

How can I center the text to the `background-color: black`? I've used absolute position and percentages, but as the window is resized, the text loses its position and creates gaps. No matter what percentages I add on either left and right side, I'm not able to center it.

[image]

```css
.theimage {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('https://www.guidedogs.org.uk/media/5105/image-of-a-puppy-sitting-sap-homepage.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: black;
  height: 300px;
}

.textdiv {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  right: 20%;
  top: 20%;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="theimage"> </div>
<div class="textdiv">text texttext text text text text text textext texttext text text text text text text text text text text tetext texttext text text texttext text text text text text text text textexttext text text text text texttext text texttext text text text textext
  text text text text text text text text</div>
```

Comment: You're better off not putting the image in the background and instead using a 2 column layout. That way, you only have to worry about centering the text in its column and you don't have to worry about the image.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems that you're referring to horizontal centering only. You don't need two `div`s. Since you put the image in the background, you can put the text inside the same `div`.

You can use simple math to achieve what you want. Your image's dimensions are 451x661, and you squished it in a 300 high `div`, so the width became 204. It seems you're trying to use 20% padding around the text, so simply add 204 to the left padding using the `calc()` function. Remember to use `box-sizing: border-box;` to make sure the padding will be included in the dimensions:

```css
.theimage {
  background-image: url('https://www.guidedogs.org.uk/media/5105/image-of-a-puppy-sitting-sap-homepage.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: black;
  height: 300px;
  /* The lines below are for the text */
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 20% 20px calc(20% + 204px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="theimage">text texttext text text text text text textext 
texttext text text text text text text text text text text tetext texttext text 
text texttext text text text text text text text textexttext text text text 
text texttext text texttext text text text textext text text text text text 
text text text</div>
```

Of course, you can also use the same idea with absolute positioning, or you can put `textdiv` inside `theimage` and use the same idea without absolute positioning:

```css
.theimage {
  background-image: url('https://www.guidedogs.org.uk/media/5105/image-of-a-puppy-sitting-sap-homepage.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-color: black;
  height: 300px;
}

.textdiv {
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 20% 20px calc(20% + 204px);
}
```

```html
<div class="theimage">
  <div class="textdiv">text texttext text text text text text
  textext texttext text text text text text text text text text
  text tetext texttext text text texttext text text text text
  text text text textexttext text text text text texttext text
  texttext text text text textext text text text text text text text text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `right: calc(50% - [image-width]px)` wich is in your case `50% - 204px;` exemple below:

html:

```
<div class="theimage"> </div>
<div class="textdiv">text texttext text text text text text textext texttext text text text text text text text text text text tetext texttext text text texttext text text text text text text text textexttext text text text text texttext text texttext text text text textext text text text text text text text text</div>
```

css:

```
    .theimage {
        background-color: red;
        background-image: url('https://www.guidedogs.org.uk/media/5105/image-of-a-puppy-sitting-sap-homepage.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        background-color: black;
        height: 300px;
    }

    .textdiv {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        right: calc(50% - 204px);
        top: 20%;
        color: white;
        text-align: justify;
    }
```

hope you get your answer )